# Delete records from multiple tables with foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Asp.Net MVC and building an E-commerce application.

I've 4 tables in my DB

`Product` which have `ProductId(PK), Name, Price, StoreId(FK)`

`Store` which have `StoreId(PK), Name, CreatedOn`

`Order` which have `OrderId(PK), StoreId(FK), OrderDate, OrderTotal`

`OrderDetail` which have `OrderDetailId(PK), OrderId(FK), Quantity, UnitPrice, Weight`

When I Try to delete a single product, it doesn't give any error and deleted the product, If I delete `Order` record it gives an error of OrderDetails foreign key, I know  I have to delete OrderDetail record first then Order record.

My scenario is, Store has multiple products, Each store has orders then order details.

Now, I don't want to delete single record every time because it takes alot of time. I want to delete a STORE and all the record from other tables (Product, Order, OrderDetails) will also be deleted. How can I do this ?

**I've tried this** This code is in my IdentityModel.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Store)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.StoreId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // also tried with TRUE, didn't work

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Store)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.StoreId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // also tried with TRUE, didn't work

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Order)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // also tried with TRUE, didn't work
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StoreDelete(int? id, Store store)
    {
        try
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            store = db.Stores.Find(id);

            if (store == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                db.Stores.Remove(store);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ManageStores", "Store");  
            }

        }

        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("StoreDelete", "Store", new { id = ViewBag.StoreId }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<h4 class="text-danger">Are you sure you want to delete this store ?</h4>
<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "inputboxes texbboxstyle form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
<br>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedOn, new { @class = "inputboxes texbboxstyle form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-danger" style="border-radius:0px; width:200px;" value="Delete" />
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MVC. This is about Entity Framework.

Comment: What didn't work? Where are the mappings for the Store class?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932720/how-does-willcascadeondelete-in-entity-framework-work The problem is that the foreign key columns are nullable, *not* a bug with WillCascadeOnDelete

Comment: Please refer this Link https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can delete multiple records from table but in order
like

```
var Order = db.Orders.where(x=>x.StoreId == store.StoreId) 
var OrderDetail = db.OrderDetails.where(x=>x.OrderId== Order.OrderId) 
var Product = db.Products.where(x=>x.StoreId == store.StoreId)

db.Orders.RemoveRange(Order);
db.OrderDetails.RemoveRange(OrderDetail);
db.Products.RemoveRange(Product);
db.Stores.Remove(store);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I hope it may works for you

Comment: Your answer really helped me and I did it but This approach is not quite good, What if I have 15 20 tables in future then I have to write alot of code for delete method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the child entities gone as well, then change the relationship to be cascade on delete and don't forget to update the model

[image]

Comment: I've also tried with .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); but didn't work

Comment: set it on the database level. set in the database the relations properties. leave C# on the sideline for now.

Comment: how ? I tried to check the properties of table, there is no INSERT and UPDATE option

Comment: Found It. Thanks (Y). I've used Database First and written Class Level Validation by DataAnnotations, I don't want to loose all that. Recently I was updating models by deleting all Models and Generating from DB again. Now that I have written code in my Models, is there any other way to update the model ?

Comment: That's why I never do CodeFirst. You have much more control using DB first

Comment: The custom Code you have written, You extract into partial classes and recreate it

Answer (score 0):

This is also working.

```
db.OrderDetail.Where(c => c.OrderDetailId == OrderDetailId).ToList()
.ForEach(db.OrderDetail.DeleteOnSubmit);

db.SubmitChanges();`
```