# EF one to many (nullable) delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm deleting a parent entity in my MVC controller and getting this error:

> [SqlException]: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.MessageThread_dbo.Listings_ListingID". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.MessageThread", column 'ListingID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

MessageThread table is mapped in EF like this:

```
// Relationships
this.HasOptional(t => t.Listing)
        .WithMany(t => t.MessageThreads)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ListingID);
```

The `ListingID` (parent) column in `MessageThread` (child) is `nullable`

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932720/how-does-willcascadeondelete-in-entity-framework-work) but the answers didn't make it work.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#enabling-cascade-delete), shouldn't the EF mapping delete the parent record and set the child `ListingID` values in `MessageThread` to `null`?

Comment: .HasForeignKey(d=>d.ListingID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: @SinanBARAN I made that change and it is the same error.

Comment: I'm sory pls can you try again.  .HasForeignKey(d=>d.ListingID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Comment: @SinanBARAN setting to true gives the same error

Comment: Are you retrieving your child objects with parent while deleting the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to delete from this table

`dbo.MessageThread", column 'ListingID'`

Because you have a Foreign Key to this table

`FK_dbo.MessageThread_dbo.Listings_ListingID`

Delete the foreign key field value first before you proceed.

or you can do it by `Cascading Deletion`
take a look at this link

[Cascading Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)