# Difference between Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>() and WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

According to [Enabling Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#enabling-cascade-delete) on Microsoft's web site:

> You can remove these cascade delete conventions by using:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
```

> The following code configures the relationship to be required and then disables cascade delete.

***C#***

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Department)
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So, as far as I understood, `Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()` removes cascade delete f**or all entities in this context**, while `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` only removes **only the related entity** (Course entity in the example above). Is that true?

Comment: The property refers to children.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932720/how-does-willcascadeondelete-in-entity-framework-work

Comment: @jdweng  Sorry, I could not understand, could you pls explain a little bit more? On the other hand, **Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>() removes cascade delete for all entities in this context, while WillCascadeOnDelete(false) only removes only the related entity (Course entity in the example above). Is that true?**

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: "Is that true?" Yes. EF appllies a set of conventions when building the model, and you can override the conventions with the fluent configuration or attributes.  Removing a convention applies to all your entities.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Many thanks David. Do you suggest to use `Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()` in general situation? And when using `Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()`, can I also use **nullable Foreign Key** in order to set child record's parent Id's = null?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Common practice is to leave the conventions and override using Fluent configuration as desired.